# Google Analytics recorded 100 new visits from multiple locations

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics suddenly showed a surge of new visits to my website from tons of different countries at the same time, I have a small community website so I am sure it was some kind of attack, I'm just not sure how it was done, I was hoping someone may be able to shed some light on this so I can make sure I am protected by it in the future

Any comments or a document to refer to would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Marc, Im sorry, i never knew i had to accept answers before, I will make sure i do this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was an attempt of a DDoS attack there is little you can do... those attacks are almost unavoidable. However, I have seen servers which minimize the impact switching to static versions of the web page on heavy load.

Perhaps it wasn't DDoS or it wasn't an attack at all... 100 clients if they're not constantly requesting content are not enough to take down a page, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eneko, I thought it was a DDoS, I have just never had the website attacked by one before, i have a dedicated server with my htaccess correctly configured so i may be ok, i will look to changing my main page to static though. Thanks again for the advice.. :-)